# "Nothing appears to have changed" after I made an edit

Tags: bug, tags, editing

[image]

I went back and made sure many times that someone hadn't added that tag right before I edited it, and it had remained exactly the same. What's going on here?

## EDIT

I *did* manage to get my edit in the review queue, but only after I made a quick word format change in the question. My question still remains, though...

Comment: FWIW had you tried to navigate to the [[tag:origins]] tag page you would see it redirects you to the [[tag:history-of]] tag page letting you know it is a synonym. The info page for the latter also shows [[tag:origins]] as a synonym on the page.

Comment: On another note in regards to the edit you managed to send to queue, making arguably poor edits (it did get rejected after all) is not a good idea, you should try and get the post in as best shape as possible, not make it worse to add a tag. If you really do think a tag should be added and you can't add it, either ask in the comments, chat or meta but don't make poor edits to get that to happen. (Although if you can't add a tag it's probably because it's a synonym of a tag already there as was the case here, the system just silently accepts the change, it could be better at notifying the user)

Comment: The edit, itself, _did not make the quality of the post lower_, it just slightly tweaked the wording.

Comment: In my opinion it made it lower because you moved a word to a position that made less sense but if you think that was okay at best all it did was "no improvement" which is a reason to reject an edit.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Agreed, there was no improvement there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag to a question already tagged [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), because **they're synonyms**, so the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag is somehow already there.

I just tried to make an edit adding the [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins) tag to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/213966/timeline). The edit went through just fine, without any error message, but it didn't actually make any change to the post and doesn't show up in the revision history.

Comment: Specifically with this tag, there was a time where there was an issue with the synonym appearing on the question as well. See [this conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/conversation/origins-synonimization).

Comment: @Alex It's a mess when tags are synonymised without being merged. Unfortunately, merges are a mod-only tool and synonymisations can be done by anyone (I wasn't a mod when I proposed this particular synonymisation, and it went through without mod intervention).